# How can I get the most fully reduced type name of an arbitrary type in a given namespace context using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am writing a function that takes any concrete or constructed `Type`, say for example `typeof(ValueTuple<Nullable<System.Int32>, double, List<string>>)` and returns a string that is the reduced C# syntax representation of that type (i.e. `(int?, double, List<string>)` in this example).

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static string ToCSharpString(this Type type, string[] usingNamespaces = null, Assembly[] usingAssemblies = null)
{
    var compilationUnit = SyntaxFactory.CompilationUnit();
    if (usingNamespaces != null)
    {
        compilationUnit = compilationUnit.AddUsings(
            Array.ConvertAll(usingNamespaces, n => SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(SyntaxFactory.ParseName(n))));
    }
    else
    {
        compilationUnit = compilationUnit.AddUsings(
            SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("System")));
    }

    MetadataReference[] metadataReferences;
    if (usingAssemblies != null)
    {
        metadataReferences = Array.ConvertAll(usingAssemblies, u => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(u.Location));
    }
    else
    {
        metadataReferences = new[]
        {
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(type.Assembly.Location)
        };
    }

    TypeSyntax typeName;
    using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
    {
        typeName = SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(provider.GetTypeOutput(new CodeTypeReference(type)));
    }

    var field = SyntaxFactory.FieldDeclaration(
        SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclaration(typeName).WithVariables(
            SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList<VariableDeclaratorSyntax>(
                SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclarator(
                    SyntaxFactory.Identifier("field")))));
    compilationUnit = compilationUnit.AddMembers(
        SyntaxFactory.ClassDeclaration("MyClass").AddMembers(
            field))
        .NormalizeWhitespace();

    var tree = compilationUnit.SyntaxTree;
    var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyAssembly", new[] { tree }, metadataReferences);
    var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
    var root = tree.GetRoot();

    var typeSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(compilationUnit
        .DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().Single()
        .Members.OfType<FieldDeclarationSyntax>().Single()
        .Declaration.Type);

    return typeSymbol.ToDisplayString(new SymbolDisplayFormat(
        typeQualificationStyle: SymbolDisplayTypeQualificationStyle.NameOnly,
        miscellaneousOptions: SymbolDisplayMiscellaneousOptions.UseSpecialTypes));
}
```

I'm attempting to string together a couple of known methods for converting types.

- Type -> Fully Qualified Name

  - via CodeDOM's CSharpCodeProvider.GetTypeOutput
- Fully Qualified Name -> TypeSyntax

  - via Rosly's SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName

Now I would like to use `.ToDisplayString()` with a few different options, but I can't find a type node for my type that doesn't return null from the semantic model.

**How can I format a TypeSyntax using a SymbolDisplayFormat?**

In addition, I expect that this *will* change `System.Int32` -> `int`, however, it won't automatically fix instances of `Nullable<T>` or `ValueTuple<T1...>`

**How can I execute the appropriate code analysis rules to replace these type names?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs state [`GetDeclaredSymbol`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.modelextensions.getdeclaredsymbol?view=roslyn-dotnet) only works for

> any type derived from MemberDeclarationSyntax, TypeDeclarationSyntax, EnumDeclarationSyntax, NamespaceDeclarationSyntax, ParameterSyntax, TypeParameterSyntax, or the alias part of a UsingDirectiveSyntax

Yours appears to be `QualifiedNameSyntax` which seems pretty much in line with the expected input but clearly means something else to Roslyn (I will admit I didn't bother checking whether it actually inherits from one of the expected types).

However, getting [`TypeInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.modelextensions.gettypeinfo?view=roslyn-dotnet) instead, seems to get your particular example working:

```cs
    var typeSymbol = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(compilationUnit // just changed this method
        .DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().Single()
        .Members.OfType<FieldDeclarationSyntax>().Single()
        .Declaration.Type); 
    return typeSymbol.Type.ToDisplayString(new SymbolDisplayFormat(
        typeQualificationStyle: SymbolDisplayTypeQualificationStyle.NameOnly,
        miscellaneousOptions: SymbolDisplayMiscellaneousOptions.UseSpecialTypes)); // I'm getting "(int?, double, List)" here
```

Comment: Wonderful.  And adding `genericsOptions: SymbolDisplayGenericsOptions.IncludeTypeParameters` gives everthing I seem to want right now: `(int?, double, List<object>)`

Comment: I gotta say, I'm pretty sure I tried this.  Folks, please don't judge me. :)

Comment: Also, I needed `NameAndContainingTypes`